# TypeScript: How to refer to other class in the same module?

Tags: typescript

I am having little issue with TypeScript. I have a module, where I have defined two classes (I will provide code below). I cannot access other class, inside the first one, and the opposite. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
module Model {

    export class Model {
        public apples:Apple[];


        getAppleCnt() {
            return this.model.apples.length;
        }

        createApple(){
            var index = this.model.apples.getAppleCnt()+1;
            return this.model.apples.push(Apple.createApple("Apple "+index,index));
        }

        createApples(){
            this.model = new Model();
            this.model.apples.=[];
        }


    }

    export class Apple {
        createApple(name:string,index:number){
            var apple = new Apple();
            apple.name = name;
            apple.index = index;
            return apple;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should either create an instance of the Apple or call static method:

```
module Model {

    export class Model {
        protected model: Model;
        public apples:Apple[];

        getAppleCnt() {
            return this.model.apples.length;
        }

        createApple(){
            var index = this.model.apples.length + 1;
            // instance 
            var apple = new Apple().createApple("Apple "+index,index);
            // or call some static method
            apple = Apple.createAppleStatic("Apple "+index,index);
            return apple;
        }

        createApples(){
            this.model = new Model();
            this.model.apples = [];
        }
    }

    export class Apple {
        public name: string;
        public index: number;

      createApple(name:string,index:number){
        var apple = new Apple();
        apple.name = name;
        apple.index = index;
        return apple;
     }
     // the same as above but static one
     static createAppleStatic(name:string,index:number){
        var apple = new Apple();
        apple.name = name;
        apple.index = index;
        return apple;
    }
   }
}
```

There is [a working playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=module%20Model%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20Model%20%7B%0A%09%09protected%20model%3A%20Model%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20apples%3AApple%5B%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20getAppleCnt()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.model.apples.length%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20createApple()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20index%20%3D%20this.model.apples.length%20%2B%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20apple%20%3D%20new%20Apple().createApple(%22Apple%20%22%2Bindex%2Cindex)%3B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20or%0A%09%09%09apple%20%3D%20Apple.createAppleStatic(%22Apple%20%22%2Bindex%2Cindex)%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20apple%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20createApples()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.model%20%3D%20new%20Model()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.model.apples%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20Apple%20%7B%0A%09%09public%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%09%09public%20index%3A%20number%3B%0A%09%09%0A%09%20%20createApple(name%3Astring%2Cindex%3Anumber)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20apple%20%3D%20new%20Apple()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20apple.name%20%3D%20name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20apple.index%20%3D%20index%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20apple%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20static%20createAppleStatic(name%3Astring%2Cindex%3Anumber)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20apple%20%3D%20new%20Apple()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20apple.name%20%3D%20name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20apple.index%20%3D%20index%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20apple%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: Can you explain me what does the static attribute exactly implies?

Comment: As in C# or Java.. static means, that this method is not belonging to instance but to a type. We can call it with a syntax typeName.publicStaticMehtod...as shown above, hope it helps a bit.. check this general https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_method

Comment: Yes! That clarifies everything! Thanks!

Comment: Great to see that ;) Enjoy Typescript, sir

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
module Model {

    export class Model {
        public apples: Apple[];


        getAppleCnt() {
            return this.apples.length;
        }

        createApple() {
            var index = this.getAppleCnt() + 1;
            return this.apples.push(Apple.createApple("Apple " + index, index));
        }

        createApples() {
            this.apples = [];
        }


    }

    export class Apple {
        name: string;
        index: number;
        static createApple(name: string, index: number) {
            var apple = new Apple();
            apple.name = name;
            apple.index = index;
            return apple;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well, however I will give a credit to @Radim, as he was first :(

Comment: Thanks for the book comment. And good choice with chosing  @RadimKöhler